# Encoded filename Telegram bot upload file

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, telegram-bot

I try to upload file using telegram bot api. File is sent but the receiver sees the encoded filename if it contains russian letters. As I found out the filename is encoded with Base64 and Utf-8

```
string url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + _keyBotTelegram + "/sendDocument";

string ttt = @"K:\Новый текстовый документ.txt";
string fileName = ttt.Split('\\').Last();
var bot = new Telegram.Bot.Api("129368276:AAEW-Q7Jv8qWaFvwYk2iD4mXZyt9Q");
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(pathToDocument, FileMode.Open))
{
    FileToSend fts = new FileToSend();
    fts.Content = stream;
    fts.Filename = pathToDocument.Split('\\').Last();
    var test = await bot.SendDocumentAsync(ChatID, fts, caption);
    // "Report",).SendPhoto("@channel Name or chat_id", fts, "My Text");
}
```

[Filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oB0x.jpg)

How to send files with unicode encoding to client to save full name of file including file extension

Tried to encode file name in Utf8

```
// Create two different encodings.
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

// Convert the string into a byte array.
byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(fileName);

// Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, utf8, unicodeBytes);

// Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
char[] utf8Chars = new char[utf8.GetCharCount(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length)];
utf8.GetChars(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length, utf8Chars, 0);
string utf8String = new string(utf8Chars);

fileName = utf8String;
```

[image: Result file name]

Comment: as far as i know Telegram API only supports UTF-8, you need to encode your characters to utf-8 (maybe this helps you: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/27)

Comment: Tried to convert file name to Utf8. It didn't help.

Comment: i don't think there is another way, how did you do the encoding? and can you post a resulting filename after sending?

Comment: i think there is something wrong with your encoding, but i didn't test it yet.

Comment: This code is taken from msdn with some correction.